# How to schedule Mandrill mail in Laravel 4?

Tags: email, laravel-4, schedule, mandrill

The Mandrill [documentation](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24331201-Can-I-schedule-a-message-to-send-at-a-specific-time-) says that the send_at parameter should be set in the mail Api call for scheduling mail.

```
Mail::send('template', array('name'=>$GLOBALS['name']), function($message)
{
    $message->to($GLOBALS['email'], $GLOBALS['name'])->subject('Subject');
});
```

In the above code where should I set the parameter: send_at

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a package for laravel that does the same thing

Maybe useful for other people:

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/abishekrsrikaanth/mailto#send-mandrill-time

Answer (score 5):

Use the X-MC-SendAt header.

```
Mail::send('template', array('name'=>$GLOBALS['name']), function($message)
{
    $message->to($GLOBALS['email'], $GLOBALS['name'])->subject('Subject');

    $headers = $message->getHeaders();
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-SendAt', '2014-09-01 01:00:00');
});
```

Note that I haven't tested this - you might need to use a different method than `addTextHeader` - refer to the swiftmailer documentation.

Refer to the documentation ([Using SMTP Headers to customize your messages](http://mandrill.zendesk.com/entries/21688056) for more details and note that the documentation does indicate that this only works for paid accounts.